# Java collection map жизнь объектов определенное время

Tags: java, коллекции

Нужен эффективный вариант хранения объектов в map определенное время.
Возможно, в java collection уже есть нужный механизм, в таком случае прошу подсказать.
Понятно, что можно сделать ConcurrentHashMap и в потоке мониторить время жизни объектов и удалять устаревшие, но не хочется костылить.

Answer (score 2):

Боюсь, что в джаве из коробки вы ничего подходящего не найдете. Но , вместе с тем, существуют коллекции, которые изначально проектировали для использования при кешировании. Такая имплементация есть у гугловых коллекций. Создается через довольно удобный билдер примерно таким образом :

```
final int TIME_TO_LIVE_CACHE_IN_HOURS = 24;
final int CACHE_MAX_SIZE = 100;
ConcurrentMap<Object, Object> map = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .maximumSize(CACHE_MAX_SIZE)
        .expireAfterWrite(TIME_TO_LIVE_CACHE_IN_HOURS, TimeUnit.HOURS)
        .build().asMap();
```